# Input form doesn't parse error and displays blank page on submit

Tags: php

**EDIT:** Changed PHP to recommended code, still can't get success/error to display on page.

I'm trying to get this contact page to work, but it seems to be breaking when I click the submit button. As soon as I click, it redirects me to /contact_form.php and shows a blank page. If all forms have been correctly filled in, the message does get sent. If any of them are wrong or not filled in, the same blank page is shown.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contact_form.php">
    <div class="input-group-lg">
        <label for="name">Your Name<i>*</i></label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What should I call you?">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-lg">
        <label for="email">Email Address<i>*</i></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-lg">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-lg">
        <label for="message">Message<i>*</i></label>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-lg">
        <label for="human">What is 2 + 2? (Anti-spam)<i>*</i></label>
        <input name="human" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2 + 2 = ?">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <?php echo $result; ?>    
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-custom"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'From: example';
    $to = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Message from X';

    $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";
    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 4) {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }
    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            print '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
            exit();
        } 
        else {
            print '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
            exit();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Dont we use `echo` to print out something???

Comment: I can't see any output in your PHP code. Why do you expect anything else than a blank page? Or are HTML and PHP concatenated in the same file? (first PHP and then HTML)

Comment: Change `$result =` in your if statement at the end of your php code to `print`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I havnt tested it, but this should work like a charm.  If you still get errors please post them.

```
if (isset ($_POST['name'])){ //RUN ONLY IF name IS SET

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$human = intval($_POST['human']);

 // Error handling for missing data
 if ((!$name) || (!$email) || (!$phone) || (!$message) || ($human !== 4)){ 
 $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>ERROR:</strong> You did not submit the following required information:</div>';

     if(!$name){ 
       $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Please enter your name</strong></div>';
     }else if(!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
       $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Please enter a valid email address</strong></div>';
     }else if(!$phone){ 
       $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Please enter a phone number</strong></div>';
     }else if(!$message){ 
       $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Please enter your message</strong></div>';
     }else if($human !== 4){ 
       $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Please correct your addition</strong></div>';
     }
 } else { // Error handling is ended, process form and send email


$from = 'From: example';
$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from X';

$body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);

   print '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
   exit();

   } // Close else after duplication checks

} else { // if the form is not posted with variables, place default empty variables so no warnings or errors show

  $name = "";
  $email = "";
  $phone = "";
  $message = "";
  $human = "";
  $result = "";

  print '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
  exit();
}
```

Comment: If this works for you, i can show you how to easily dress this up.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `print` or `echo` statement in your PHP file ...

add `echo $result` to the end of your PHP file to see the results

Answer (score 0):

Change your success code this.  This will print your success or error msg on page reload.

```
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            print '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
            exit();
        } else {
            print '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changed my code to that. Now when it's succesful, I see the success message on a new page, with just the line of text. On a failure, I still get a blank page.

How do I parse the error message as well and how I get them both to show up on the actual html page?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your php page.  when writing php i always add this to the top when building.  it will display all of your errors.  Then paste your errors here

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: errName in /contact_form.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined variable: errEmail in /contact_form.php on line 33

Comment: Your error variables only exist if the error is present, soo.
`if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }`

should be

`if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }else{ $errMessage = ''; }`

That sets the variable even tho the error isnt present.  But it displays nothing.  In php a variable always needs to equal something.  Set all of your errors that way.  Or you can set all of them at the top of the page.  `$errMessage = ''; $errEmail = ''; $errHuman = ''; $errName = '';`

Comment: Also, your error msg cant print because if the error is present, your if !errName etc statement wont work.  I am rebuilding your php code and will paste it as new answer shortly.

Comment: Check my new answer and let me know.  Continue using error reporting and post any errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Determine if a variable is set:**

```
 if (!isset($errName) && !isset($errEmail) && !isset($errMessage) && !isset($errHuman)) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='í<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    }
    if(isset($result)){
    echo $result;}
```